# Supplying call latency as a IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to make use of Java 8 and streams and one of the things I am trying to replace is a system we have where we

- Use an aspect to measure call latency (per config period of time) to out webservices and then
- Feed those results into a Complex Event Processor (esper) so that
- We can send out alert notifications

So, one step at a time. For the first step, I need to produce a stream (I think) that allows me to feed those latency numbers into existing listeners. Understanding that, getting the next number in series might have to wait until there is a call.

How can I do that? Here is the latency aspect with comments.

```
public class ProfilingAspect {

    private ProfilingAction action;

    public ProfilingAspect(ProfilingAction action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public Object doAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object retVal = null;
        Throwable error = null;
        try{
            retVal = jp.proceed();
        }catch (Throwable t){
            error = t;
        }

        Class withinType = jp.getSourceLocation().getWithinType();
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long runningTime = endTime - startTime;
        // Let the IntStream know we have a new latency. Or really, we have an object 
        // stream with all this extra data
        action.perform(withinType, methodName, jp.getArgs(), runningTime, error);

        if( error != null ){
            throw error;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a working example. It doesn't handle the situation where I have to buffer up results though is the stream isn't being read fast enough. I am open to some improvement

```
public class LatencySupplier implements Supplier<SomeFancyObject> {

    private Random r = new Random();

    @Override
    public SomeFancyObject get() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100 + r.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return new SomeFancyObject(10 + r.nextInt(1000));
    }
}

public class SomeFancyObject {

    private static String[] someGroups = {"Group1","Group2","Group3"};
    private final String group;

    private int value;

    public SomeFancyObject(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.group = WSRandom.selectOne(someGroups);
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + "";
    }
}
```

My next step is to create a stream by time so I can do avg/5 min, etc.

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        Stream<SomeFancyObject> latencyStream = Stream.generate(new LatencySupplier());
        Map<Object,List<SomeFancyObject>> collect = latencyStream.limit(10).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sfo -> sfo.getGroup()));
        System.out.println(collect);
        Object o = new Object();
        synchronized (o){
            o.wait();
        }

    }

}
```